# Android: issue with data storage (SharedPreferences)

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, data-storage

I'm learning android and for this project I need to save user's data - color change of buttons, in this case -. During the program the change occurs (onClick), but when I restart the app, nothing happens - the change has not been saved (or read...)  Can someone help me? Code:

```
   final String paintKey = "paint";

   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    buttonCreate();
    preferences();
    togglePlay();
}

   public void preferences(){ //the issue in this method?

    SharedPreferences settings =   PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    data = settings.getString("stage", "Indoors");
    settings.getBoolean(paintKey,false);

    String backGround = settings.getString("stage", "Indoors");

    if (backGround.equals("Indoors")) {
        Picasso.with(this).load(R.drawable.shocked_crowd).fit().centerCrop().into(stage);

    }
    if (backGround.equals("Street")) {
        Picasso.with(this).load(R.drawable.coins).fit().centerCrop().into(stage);

    }
}

public void changeColor(){
    if(!paint) {    //paint variable has global scope and it is set to false
        c1.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);

        paint = true;
    }else{
        c1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

        paint = false;
    }
    SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("paint", paint);
    editor.commit();
}
```

EDIT: the onClick method:

public void onClick(View v) {

```
    if(v==color){

       changeColor();
    }
```

EDIT: this is how I have it now:

```
public void preferences(){

    SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    data = settings.getString("stage", "Indoors");
    final String paintKey = "paint";
    settings.getBoolean(paintKey,false);
```

Wrong? if I put editor instead of settings i get red underlined

Comment: I don't see a piece of code reading from "paint" key: `settings.getBoolean("paint", false)`. You should read the very same key you were saving to. Ideally make a `final String paintKey = "paint"` variable.

Comment: I've addedthe line but it didnt worked...also the final string

Comment: Please update the question and actual behaviour accordingly

Comment: I've updated the code as you told, still not working, when I exit the app the button stays in it's initial state (white)

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't see reading from paintKey settings. Besides, now you should be saving it like this: `editor.putBoolean(paintKey, paint);`

Comment: I'm exiting the app through the "mobile" button, i dont have an exit button, can this be the problem?

Comment: the final string has global scope and the save is like you wrote...i dont get it...:public void preferences(){

        SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
              settings.getBoolean(paintKey,false);

Comment: okay, what is the result of `settings.getBoolean(paintKey,false);`? It should contain the value you were previously saving with `editor.putBoolean(paintKey, paint);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129301/discussion-between-glassraven-and-foxanna).

Comment: Remember that Java requires methods to be inside a class. For clarity, your code snippets should be complete and include the class just like you have it in your actual code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to work with `SharedPreferences` you need a global key

```
final String paintKey = "paint"
```

To write boolean value info `SharedPreferences` use

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
editor.putBoolean(paintKey, paint).commit();
```

To read that data later

```
paint = settings.getBoolean(paintKey, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
settings.getBoolean(paintKey,false);
```

This line gets a value from the SharedPreferences and promptly ignores it. You must save the return value in a variable in order to use it later:

```
boolean paint = settings.getBoolean(paintKey,false);
```

This will create a local variable that can only be used in the same method. If you need to use the value in other methods, create a field instead.